# Apply a converter to all elements in Json Array

Tags: c#, json.net

One can use custom converters by defining a class like this:

```
public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyCustomType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var ret = new MyCustomType();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And then using it like this:

```
MyCustomType item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomType>(jsonString, new MyCustomTypeConverter());
```

My question is, how can I apply this deserializer when dealing with a list of `MyCustomType`? Basically I have a Json array (`[{ ... }, { ... }]`) and I would like to use the converter above on each item of the array to get a `List<MyCustomType>`.

I know I can do it by hand using the `JArray` object and its methods but I was wondering if there was an easier and cleaner way to do it.

---

Here's a simplified context.

C# (I want to deserialize a `List` of those):

```
class MyCustomType
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

JSON (one item in the array sample):

```
{
    "Id": 50,
    "Data": [
        "Hello",
        "World"
    ]
}
```

C# Deserialization I want to apply:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var ret = new MyCustomType();
    ret.Data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var value = reader.Value.ToString();
        switch(value)
        {
            case "Id":
                ret.Id = reader.ReadAsInt32().Value;
                break;
            case "Data":
                ret.Data.Add(MySingleton.Instance.CurrentLanguage, reader.ReadAsString());
                break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Post a real json and explain what you want get from it (like how MycustomType is defined).

Comment: Added a simplified context to the post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While [L.B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21804193/1430156) works, there are cases where a converter is indeed necessary - for instance, when you don't ever get to touch the raw JSON and only get to attribute ASP.NET methods that will be accessible to HTTP requests.

In that case, you can use the [`JsonPropertyAttribute` class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) and assign a value to its [`ItemConverterType` property](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm):

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(MyCustomConverter))]
public List<MyCustomType> Items { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not sure why you where downvoted? This is the simplest, natively supported, answer. Unfortunately the poor Json.Net docs squirrel info like this away on pages that never turn up on search engines.

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomType>(json);
```

if your json is an array then use

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyCustomType>>(json);
```

And if you can change the type of `Data` to `List<string>`, you don't even need *jsonConverter*

---

```
public class MyCustomType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomConverter))]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyCustomType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // read the string array and convert it to dictionary 
        // as declared in your MyCustomType
        var arr = serializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(reader);
        return arr.ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);
    }
}
```

## EDIT

Just deserialize as

```
var yourObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomType.Rootobject>(yourjson);
```

---

```
public class MyCustomType
{

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Datum[] data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string al { get; set; }
        public string[] datapsi { get; set; }
        public string[] tags { get; set; }
        public string partype { get; set; }
        public Info info { get; set; }
        public Factors factors { get; set; }
        public Espace[] espace { get; set; }
        public Annex Annex { get; set; }
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public string nopub { get; set; }
        public int nodem { get; set; }
    }

    public class Factors
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public float b { get; set; }
        public int c { get; set; }
        public float d { get; set; }
        public int e { get; set; }
        public float f { get; set; }
        public float g { get; set; }
        public int h { get; set; }
        public int i { get; set; }
        public int j { get; set; }
        public int k { get; set; }
        public int l { get; set; }
        public float m { get; set; }
        public int n { get; set; }
        public int o { get; set; }
        public int p { get; set; }
        public float q { get; set; }
        public float r { get; set; }
        public int s { get; set; }
        public float t { get; set; }
    }

    public class Annex
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
    }

    public class Espace
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Datatip datatip { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public string resource { get; set; }
        public int delta { get; set; }
        public int[] target { get; set; }
        public string targetType { get; set; }
        public string targetOneLined { get; set; }
        public int[] alx { get; set; }
        public string alxOneLined { get; set; }
        public int[][] damps { get; set; }
        public string[] dampsOneLined { get; set; }
        public Var[] vars { get; set; }
        public object misc { get; set; }
        public string miscOneLined { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datatip
    {
        public string[] label { get; set; }
        public string[] damps { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public string full { get; set; }
        public string sprite { get; set; }
        public string group { get; set; }
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
        public int w { get; set; }
        public int h { get; set; }
    }

    public class Var
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public float coeff { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how do I handle the `Id` property? this is a simplified context, `MyCustomType` is actually a much more complicated object with its own sub-objects that need to be converted as well

Comment: @RedPolygon In fact, i don't think you need JsonConverter in your case. Even if you have a complex object. Just post your real json so that we can post a *working* answer.

Comment: Here is a raw Json : http://pastebin.com/J5iBuxd7. I have added some comments (using `//`) even though I know comments aren't part of `JSON`. I haven't commented all the lines needing a conversion to a `Dictionary` but you'll get the idea :)

Comment: The problem is, there are plenty of type mismatch. For instance, `Datum.datapsi` is of type `Dictionary<string, string[]>`, not `string[]` (even though in the Json it *is* an array of `string`). I have no control over the model and that is why I need a converter (they keys of the `Dictionary` are *not* part of the `Json` and come from an independant source). Thanks for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: @RedPolygon `For instance, Datum.datapsi is of type Dictionary<string, string[]>, not string[]` I think I explained how you can do this in the first part of my answer.